# Remplaza un html tag a través de jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

tengo un sliderbar de [bootstrap seiyria](http://seiyria.com/bootstrap-slider/) (ejemplo #19)

¿Cómo puedo alterar el contenido de éste con jquery -replace-?

Mi principal meta es que si doy clic en el botón, el contenido del slider se modifique:

```
          <span id="ex18-label-1" class="hidden">Example slider label</span>
          <input id="ex19" type="text"
          data-provide="slider"
          data-slider-ticks="[1, 2, 3]"
          data-slider-ticks-labels='["short", "medium", "long"]'
          data-slider-min="1"
          data-slider-max="3"
          data-slider-step="1"
          data-slider-value="3"
          data-slider-tooltip="hide" />

          <br/>
          <br/>
          <br/>
           <button id="myButton">Change bar</button>
```

Del lado de javascript, texty ya tiene el valor que quiero que tenga el slider, seguramente aquí está mi error:

```
  var texty = ' <input id="ex19" type="text" data-provide="slider"data-slider-ticks="[1, 2, 3]" data-slider-ticks-labels='["Pequeño", "Mediano", "Grande"]' data-slider-min="1" data-slider-max="3" data-slider-step="1"   data-slider-value="3" data-slider-tooltip="hide" />'

             $('#myButton').click(function() {
             $("#ex18-label-1").replaceWith(texty);
             });
```

necesitan las sig. librerías para que les funcione el slider:

```
http://seiyria.com/bootstrap-slider/js/bootstrap-slider.js
http://seiyria.com/bootstrap-slider/css/bootstrap-slider.css
http://seiyria.com/bootstrap-slider/dependencies/css/bootstrap.min.css
http://seiyria.com/bootstrap-slider/dependencies/js/modernizr.js
```

Las barras inicialmente dicen: 
"short", "medium", "long"

Después del click en el botón tiene que mostrar: 
"Pequeño", "Mediano", "Grande"

[Aquí está el enlace al jsFidle.](https://jsfiddle.net/nacs2025/L7pn58rt/)

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que no funciona?

Comment: Actualicé la publicación al pie explico de otra manera. Gracias por interesarte.

Comment: No estaría entendiendo porque quieres hacer eso? por pura curiosidad, a que se debe ese cambio? para hacerlo multi-lenguaje?

Comment: Se debe algo diferente, pero hice esta es una pregunta de esta manera sin darle tantas vueltas al asunto, en sí si quieres redacto nuevamente la pregunta pq no se si me funcione como has mostrado en tu ejemplo,  tengo una webpage que inicialmente muestra un modal filtro de fecha en base a la fecha que filtre el usuario (meses) éstos son los que se mostrarán en el en sliderbar del webpage final.

Comment: Si lo vemos con otros datos, la variable texty tendria que ir así:

Comment: var texty = ' <input id="ex19" type="text" data-provide="slider"data-slider-ticks="[1, 2, 3, 4]" data-slider-ticks-labels='["Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo", "Abril"]' data-slider-min="1" data-slider-max="4" data-slider-step="1"   data-slider-value="4" data-slider-tooltip="hide" />'

Comment: Y puede cambiar...en base a lo que el usuario elija.

Answer (score 4):

Si la idea es simplemente cambiar los textos (labels), puedes recorrerlos con .each() y almacenar los nuevos textos en el mismo orden, y reemplazar el texto correspondiente:

```js
var spanishLabels = ["Pequeño", "Mediano", "Grande"];
$('#myButton').click(function() {
  $('.slider-tick-label').each(function(index) {
    $(this).text(spanishLabels[index]);
  });           
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://seiyria.com/bootstrap-slider/js/bootstrap-slider.js"></script>
<link href="http://seiyria.com/bootstrap-slider/css/bootstrap-slider.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="http://seiyria.com/bootstrap-slider/dependencies/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<span id="ex18-label-1" class="hidden">Example slider label</span>
          <input id="ex19" type="text"
          data-provide="slider"
          data-slider-ticks="[1, 2, 3]"
          data-slider-ticks-labels='["short", "medium", "long"]'
          data-slider-min="1"
          data-slider-max="3"
          data-slider-step="1"
          data-slider-value="3"
          data-slider-tooltip="hide" />

          <br/>
          <br/>
          <br/>
           <button id="myButton">Change bar</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Para poder cambiar el **slider**, te recomiendo colocarlo dentro de una `<div>` y luego cambiar su contenido por un nuevo slider, en el siguiente ejemplo te muestro como hacer:

```js
$('#myButton').on("click",function() {
$("#divEx19").slider({
 "ticks":[1, 2, 3],
 "ticks_labels":["Pequeño", "Mediano", "Grande"],
 "min":1,
 "max":3,
 "step":1,
 "value":3,
 "tooltip":"hide"
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://seiyria.com/bootstrap-slider/js/bootstrap-slider.js"></script>
<link href="http://seiyria.com/bootstrap-slider/css/bootstrap-slider.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="http://seiyria.com/bootstrap-slider/dependencies/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<span id="ex18-label-1" class="hidden">Example slider label</span>
<div id="divEx19">
 <input id="ex19" type="text"
  data-provide="slider"
  data-slider-ticks="[1, 2, 3]"
  data-slider-ticks-labels='["short", "medium", "long"]'
  data-slider-min="1"
  data-slider-max="3"
  data-slider-step="1"
  data-slider-value="3"
  data-slider-tooltip="show" />
</div>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<button id="myButton">Change bar</button>
```

espero esto te ayude.