# Remplaza un html tag mediante de jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, bootstrap

Cuando inicialmente la website abre, aparece un modal de bootstrap que pide filtrar fecha.

La fecha se  filtra (ejemplo: Abril 2016). Se hace clic en el botón ACEPTAR y la magia ocurre, el servidor me arroja los datos para llenar todo un dashboard de pie a cabeza.

En una sección del dashboard, existen unas gráficas pastel y un slider (trackbar) , Cada tick en el slider refleja los meses del año (Ene. - Dic.) Gracias a ésto cada vez que deslizo el trackbar se ejecuta un webmethod que actualiza las gráficas pastel con datos correspondiente al mes consultado.

Mi error radica en que , si el usuario inicialmente en modal filtró una fecha de abril 2016... y luego en la sección de las gráficas pastel (slider de enero a dic.) se filtra por ejemplo dic. se crea un conflicto. Ya que el webmethod "NO" consulta nuevamente el motor de bases de datos sino, unas variables de tipo estáticas del lado del servidor que almacenan dicha consulta inicial - Ésto para reducir tiempo de espera que la consulta no se vuelva a ejecutar.

Por ende una de mis primeras soluciones que se me vino a la mente para no desarmar el código inicial de la consulta, es modificar éste trackbar, al momento de filtrar mes en el modal de bootstrap, o sea que si yo filtré mes abril 2016: al darle clic, el html tag del slider será construido cuando el evento se ejecute. En vez del default de enero a diciembre, ahora el slider mostrará valores de enero a abril limitando al usuario la consulta ya que incialmente cargó datos hasta abril (abril es una variable, abril es ejemplo).

Otra idea que se me ocurría era construir el slider de enero a dic , y solo pasar los meses que iban a estár desabilitados, pero el proveedor del pluggin creo que se quedó corto en ésto.

Bien, este es el modal:

```
      <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">

                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
                            ×
                        </button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title center" id="myModalLabel">
                            Seleccione Fecha
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
             <h4>Año:</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-12">
                <select size="4" name="DDLAno" multiple="multiple" id="DDLAno">
            <option value="2013">2013</option>
            <option value="2014">2014</option>
            <option value="2015">2015</option>
            <option value="2016">2016</option>

                </select>                 
                </div>



        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
             <h4>Mes:</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-12">
                <select name="DDLMes" id="DDLMes" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" style="width:100%; max-width:400px; height:40px; font-family:'Segoe UI'; font-size:100%;">
            <option value="enero">enero</option>
            <option value="febrero">febrero</option>
            <option value="marzo">marzo</option>
            <option value="abril">abril</option>
            <option value="mayo">mayo</option>
            <option value="junio">junio</option>
            <option value="julio">julio</option>
            <option value="agosto">agosto</option>
            <option value="septiembre">septiembre</option>
            <option value="octubre">octubre</option>
            <option value="noviembre">noviembre</option>
            <option value="diciembre">diciembre</option>

            </select>

                </div>
                </div>
                    </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">                   
                        <input type="submit" name="btnfecha" value="Aceptar" id="btnfecha" class="btn btn-default" />

                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
```

Éste es el slider:

```
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="http://seiyria.com/bootstrap-slider/js/bootstrap-slider.js"></script>
            <link href="http://seiyria.com/bootstrap-slider/css/bootstrap-slider.css" rel="stylesheet">
            <link href="http://seiyria.com/bootstrap-slider/dependencies/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <input id="ex19" type="text"
          data-provide="slider"
          data-slider-ticks="[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]"
          data-slider-ticks-labels='["Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo", "Junio", "Julio", "Agosto", "Septiembre", "Octubre", "Noviembre", "Diciembre"]'
          data-slider-min="1"
          data-slider-max="12"
          data-slider-step="1"
          data-slider-value="6"
          data-slider-tooltip="hide"/>
```

Gracias por ayudar, no es necesario que halen la información desde el modal; Un ejemplo con cualquier botón que modifique el slider estaría genial para mi, luego veo como obtener la variable del modal.

Les dejo [aquí igual un html file compartido en google drive](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0lENlJfA5GrMjVoblRNZjR6bVk) que lo pueden echar a andar sin ningun inconveniente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[Aquí está el jsFiddle del slider.](https://jsfiddle.net/nacs2025/L7pn58rt/)

Comment: La alternativa de solo mostrar los meses anteriores al elegido (incluído) me parece correcta. ¿Para qué mostrar los meses que no se desean?

Comment: Si exacto, para alcanzar ello tengo que construir el trackbar en el evento y es donde estoy pegado. Hasta el momento tengo un default en el html que muestra hasta diciembre.

Comment: ¿tienes código para crear el trackbar o no sabes cómo hacerlo?

Comment: El código html y las librerías necesarias jquery y css las deje en el post principal. en la sección que dice: Éste es el slider. Lo que solicito es cómo modificar éste slider cuando se ejecute el evento clic. mi nota se extiende a que el ejemplo que ustedes puedan proveerme no necesariamente esté relacionada con el modal por ahora, con un boton de prueba que modifique el contenido del trackbar en el evento clic me basta de ejemplo.

Comment: Desde mi punto de vista veo varias cosas y todas son diferentes, todas las que mencionas son posibles, sin embargo, no vi una linea de javascript. Ahora, yo te recomendaría hacer un script en el backend que te devuelva las variables que necesitas para armar el dashboard, de está manera cada vez que modifiques algun valor lo pasarias por una llamada ajax actualizando los parametros. Jalar la información del modal también es posible, incluso si está oculto. También es posible obtener el valor del slider.

Comment: Entiendo, si tengo un scrpit pero no es 100% funcional como quisiera.  http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/25263/remplaza-un-html-tag-a-trav%C3%A9s-de-jquery/25265#25265   Esa respuesta es un acercamiento paralelamente a lo que quiero, pero al no darme entender la respuesta ha sido desviada y tiene muy pocas visitas.

Comment: ¿Podrías crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable?¿Y cómo es esta pregunta diferente a la que planteas con casi igual título y que [enlazas justo arriba](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/25263/remplaza-un-html-tag-a-trav%C3%A9s-de-jquery/)?

Comment: Mira este archivo HTML, no sé pq el JSfiddle no me funciona.  https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0lENlJfA5GrMjVoblRNZjR6bVk

Comment: Sigue sin quedarme claro lo que se pregunta (debo ser el único). ¿Qué es lo que estás intentando hacer?

Comment: Mira, trato de construir el slider a través de un clic. El botón le pasará el parametro de meses.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En html y jquery me quedé corto esta vez.

Estoy trabajando en ASP.NET del lado del cliente establecí:

```
   <input id="ex19" type="text" data-provide="slider" runat="server" />
```

Del lado del servidor al ejecutar el evento clic del botón mando a ejecutar el siguiente código:

```
        List<string> meses_nom = new List<string>();


        ddl_mes_int.ForEach(delegate(int jk)
        {
            meses_nom.Add("\" " + CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(jk).ToUpper() + " \"");             
        });

        ex19.Attributes.Add("data-slider-ticks", "[" + String.Join(", ", ddl_mes_int) + "]");
        ex19.Attributes.Add("data-slider-ticks-labels", "[ " + String.Join(", ", meses_nom) + " ]");
        ex19.Attributes.Add("data-slider-min", "1");
        ex19.Attributes.Add("data-slider-max", ddl_mes_int.Count.ToString());
        ex19.Attributes.Add("data-slider-step", "1");
        ex19.Attributes.Add("data-slider-value", ddl_mes_int.Count.ToString());
        ex19.Attributes.Add("data-slider-tooltip", "hide");
```

Donde el ddl_mes_int (lista tipo int) ya contiene los valores que el usuario seleccionó en el modal.

Así que cuando se ejecuta este evento el slider se modifica.